# jQuery encodeURI for href not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I'm having problems encoding a string so I can place a variable into a link.  I'm sure this is really simple, but i had trouble turning anything up.

```
$("a.inquiry").attr("href", "/inquiry/6933/text=" + encodeURI("text o"));
```

This doesn't work.

```
encodeURI("text o")
```

Still returns:

```
link/text o
```

Instead of:

```
link/text%20
```

Also tried:

```
$("a.inquiry").attr("href", encodeURIComponent("/inquiry/6933/text=" + "text o"));
```

Comment: As you tagged this question with *encodeuricomponent*, haven’t you tried that?

Comment: encodeURIComponent should work. I've tried the sample you've provided and it seems working. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/XdJCM/.

Answer (score 17):

Try with [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) instead.

Comment: that does work either ;-( either its not working or something else I'm doing is undoing the encoding afterwards?

Comment: @holden: It could be so, `encodeURIComponent` has worked for me always.

Comment: not working with me also, actually working with comma but not for spaces

Answer (score 6):

I thought I was having the same problem, but then I realized I was looking at the results in both the mouseOver of the resulting link and in the address bar after clicking the link. It turns out that my browser was showing the spaces in both cases - i.e. when I copied the URI out of the address bar and pasted it in emacs the %20 revealed itself.

Comment: Wow, this was the solution for me too.